# System.Timers.Timer sometimes stops and then resumes after a while

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, timer

Let's have a class that every 5 seconds refreshes a key in Redis. (We call it "dead man switch").
The problem is, once per several days it just stops emitting the Elapsed event for a brief period of time, from seconds to 1-2 minutes.

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace My
{
    public class Test : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Test> _logger;
        private readonly IDatabase _redis;
        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        public Test(ILogger<Test> logger, IDatabase redis)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _redis = redis;
            _timer = new Timer {Interval = 5000};
            _timer.Elapsed += Beat;

            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Beat(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Pushing DMS.");
            _redis.StringSet("1234", "OK", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), When.Always, CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
            _logger.LogInformation("DMS Pushed.");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing.");
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```r
...
[08:08:40 INF] Pushing DMS.
[08:08:40 INF] DMS pushed.
[08:08:45 INF] Pushing DMS.
[08:08:45 INF] DMS pushed.
[08:08:50 INF] Pushing DMS.
[08:08:50 INF] DMS pushed.
[08:09:17 INF] Pushing DMS.               #<-- Here's a 27s gap
[08:08:17 INF] DMS pushed.
[08:08:23 INF] Pushing DMS.
[08:08:23 INF] DMS pushed.
...
```

These events do not queue up - it just creates a gap.
This class is a part of bigger project running in a kubernetes cluster.

I've googled up a theory that it can be caused by threadpool starvation so I added debug logging of threadpool state, but it IMO does not bring up any relevant information:

```cs
        private void Beat(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ptc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
            ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var maxWt, out var maxCpt);
            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out var wt, out var cpt);
            var current = ThreadPool.ThreadCount;
            var pending = ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount;
            var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            _logger.LogDebug(
                $"Pushing DMS.\nTP state: Thread#: {threadId} \t#Current: {current}\t #Pending: {pending}\t#WorkerT: {wt}/{maxWt}\t #CompletionT: {cpt}/{maxCpt}\n#ProcessT: {ptc}");
            _redis.StringSet("1234", "OK", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), When.Always, CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
            _logger.LogInformation("DMS Pushed.");
        }
```

Resulting log:

```r
[02:31:13 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 92    #Current: 8  #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32760/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:31:13 INF] DMS Pushed.
[02:31:18 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 47    #Current: 11     #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32760/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:31:18 INF] DMS Pushed.
[02:31:23 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 47    #Current: 11     #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32761/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:31:23 INF] DMS Pushed.
[02:31:28 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 92    #Current: 8  #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32760/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:31:28 INF] DMS Pushed.

# HERE COMES THE GAP

[02:33:01 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 103   #Current: 8  #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32760/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:33:01 INF] DMS Pushed.
[02:33:06 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 55    #Current: 10     #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32762/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:33:06 INF] DMS Pushed.
[02:33:11 INF] Pushing DMS.
               TP state: Thread#: 103   #Current: 10     #Pending: 0    #WorkerT: 32762/32767    #CompletionT: 1000/1000
#ProcessT: 46
[02:33:11 INF] DMS Pushed.
```

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this behavior?

Comment: You said this is part of a larger application; do you have any logging of what the application is doing when those gaps occur? My instinct is to say that something is blocking on the `Timer`'s thread.

Comment: Also, what does `LogInformation` do? Does it write to a file or a database?

Comment: Might be that system CPU is overloaded and timer just doesn't get a chance to run, or for example long garbage collection occurs (during which all threads are paused).

Comment: network protocol dropping packets if not tcp?  i just saw a demo with kubernetes and one of the workers was laggy, resolution was switch to a different worker with less load

Comment: @WSC In most cases, gap happens when EF is waiting for DB update. Sometimes EF.SaveChanges but even raw sql execution. (DB is on a separated VM) I can see DB spike up while this app server cools down in that time.

*LogInformation* is serilog stdout + 2 other sink: ELK and fire-and-forget redis.

Comment: @Evk Thing is we don't see any relevant CPU spikes at the times. The App is ironicaly waiting for DB execution. The GC should be a topic, though ..
@ChristopherHoffman I might be missing your point but there isn't any "non-tcp" communication. According to the logs, the redis is always called but in some periods the `Beat` function is not being called at all.

Comment: GC collection?...

Comment: "gap happens when EF is waiting for DB update" - Haven't you answered your question there? Sounds like your DB is taking a while to respond for some reason and the app is waiting for a response. Is it possible you've got contention (multiple instances of app trying to update same table(s))?

Comment: @WSC Yes, the DB query (it's a stored procedure) can take long time and execution og that thread is blocked. But could you please explain me, in which way this can influence a timer that should be operating at completely different thread? I don't get it.

Comment: Have you considered using a dedicated thread for sending the periodic `Beat`? The `System.Timers.Timer` uses threads from the `ThreadPool` to invoke the event handlers, so it is less reliable than a dedicated thread because it depends on the `ThreadPool` availability.

Comment: I'd add logging for GC start/end events, to rule out this possibility. And I agree with Theodor above to try dedicated thread, to rule out problems with thread pool (just in case).

Comment: @rudolfdobias My thought was that if your procedure takes 30 seconds to run, and is run every 5 seconds, you've got an ever increasing backlog. Eventually, you run out of threads in the threadpool which aren't being taken up waiting for the stored procedure response. No idea how realistic that is, though.

Comment: @WSC I get it now, there was a misunderstanding. The DB procedure runs outside of this class and this class is only a "beacon" that emits a single redis command every 5s.